# Uploading files down SSL/TLS protocol with Python

Tags: python, ssl, upload

I have a Python script that upload a file with Dropbox API. How do I create a connection with socket and SSL/TLS protocol for uploading files down this protocol? I took a look in SSL python module, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wont need to worry about SSL/TLS and stuff here if you are using the DrobBox Core API. An example is provided [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/python).